# PDO_ODBC accessing IBM DB2 tables with special characters in the table names

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework2, db2, odbc

I'm working on a DB2 table on as/400. I'm trying to run a basic query against it but the table name contains a `.` in it. For example: `my.table` is the table name.

The problem is that PDO believes that I'm specifying a database name `my` with my table name `table`. Hence the prepared statement is failing and saying no such table `table` exists in database `my`. Changing the table name is not an option.

What is the best way to handle a period in the table name? I've tried escaping the period but haven't had any success.

Here's some example code of my problem:

```
$sql= "select * from '[THE.TABLE]'";
        try {
            $statement = $this->db->query($sql);
            $results = $statement->execute();
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                print_r($result);
            }
            exit;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            //log issue and other stuff
        }
```

The application is running in Zend Framework 2.

Comment: Try putting backticks around table name: `\`my.table\``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: I tried the back ticks as well. It didn't work.

Comment: IMHO, I don't think this is a duplicate because I'm not using MySQL but rather DB2 via ODBC. I'm fairly new to this type of Database access but I've tried the quotes and backticks already without success.

Comment: PDO don't know nothing about table names and don't care for them. What error do you get?

Comment: I've solved it thanks to @aynber referencing the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand corrected. As aynber mentioned in a comment, the solution was to use double quotes escaped correctly. The answer could be found in the question directed towards MySQL.